# Application not closing fully, No idea why

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have an application that opens like this: (Program.cs)

```
        Main MainForm = new Main();
        Application.Run();
```

if the user does not specify /hide option, then the program shows like this:
(Main.cs)

```
internal Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Show();
}
```

Sometime, the program needs to close immediatly if a file does not exist. So I close it like this: (Main.cs)

```
private void MainLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.exist("FilePath")
        this.Close();
}
```

on FormClosed, I have this:

```
Application.ExitThread();
```

This destoy's almost everything from the application, including the Taskbar icon. However, on Visual Studio, the program is still "Running" until I click "Stop Debugging". 
Anyone has any idea why this is happening ?

Objective: I want to start the program minimized(No Flash screen shown) if the user specify /hide argument.
The program will automatically close if a certain file is not found.

Comment: hope your users appreciate why to program doesn't start (or stops) without notifying

Comment: That's not the issue. Ofcourse, I will add the notifications. Right now, just for testing purpose I am trying to figure this out.

Comment: The problem is Application.Run().  Without a form given, it won't add an event handler for the form's closed event, and won't terminate the message loop when the form is closed.  See also: Application.Exit().

Comment: I don't think it's the FormClosed event. That event is being called because I do start a form with this.Show(). I tested and FormClosed is being called and even with Application.ExitThread/Exit, there is stil something running...

Comment: I'm sure FormClosed is raised.  What I meant is that Application won't know to terminate the message loop when your form is closed, so it must be explicitly done.  Application.Exit should terminate all message loops; you should be able to verify it by setting a breakpoint after Application.Run.  Are you creating any background threads, by chance?

Comment: First of all, I'd like to say thank you for the help. And yes, I will have background threads but none of them are activated until I figure this out. I am a little confused, where should I use Application.Exit ? I been trying it but still the program remains in running. If I start the program and click "Close" button then it closes perfectly, but when I have it automatically close on MainLoad() that's when it gets stuck running.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "foreground thread" above, not background.  The former will prevent the process from terminating until they exit.  The main UI thread is the only foreground thread in the process unless you create additional foreground threads.  At any rate, can you verify that Application.Run is returning in your "still running" repro?  In the debugger's threads window, which threads are still running?

Comment: There is 1 "Unknown" thread that was destroyed, 5 worker thread, 3 no-names, 2(.Net SystemEvents, .vshost.RunParkingWindow), and 1 Main Thread.
Enviroment.Exit(0); fixed the problem but I'm not sure if that's the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `this.Close();`, try using `Environment.Exit();`

Comment: Hello, Enviroment.Exit(0) works well, however, Notify-icon picture is still left in the task bar. Any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: Is it still there after you mouse over the icon, or does it disappear at that point? If it's the latter, this is known bug in Windows itself, and the way around it is to explicitly hide the notification icon from your code before calling Environment.Exit()

Comment: It disappears, yea that was my plan.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in Program Main.

```
if (!File.Exists("FilePath"))
        {
            return;
        }
```

In your form load specify below:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```